# Can I add a Sammy route after run()

Tags: sammy.js

I have Sammy working just fine.  I want to dynamically at some point addHowever I want to add a route to Sammy after the run() is invoked.  Is this possible?

All my routes work that are specified before Sammy.run.  However I have some dynamic routes I want to add at a later point in time.

Thanks in advance, Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You could define new routes after the run method. But, the initial route callback will not fire when you load the page. If you invoke the run(on dom ready) after you define your routes, sammy will fire the callback for the current route.

For example. 
If you define 2 routes after run method

- #/
- #/List

and you hit the following url - www.mysite.com/index.html#/, the callback for #/ route will not be invoked.

I suggest calling app.runRoute('get', location.hash) or something similar to get the first route to fire.

Some code:

```
$(function()
    {
        app.run();

        app.get('#/', function()
        {
            alert('home');
        });

        app.get('#/list', function()
        {
            alert('list');
        });

        app.runRoute('get', location.hash);
    });
```

FYI Durandal 2.0 allows for child routes. Maybe have a look at.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Part of my problem is that I had a route previously defined with an empty string url like ''.  I changed that to something like 'dashboard' and then started Sammy with sammy.run('#/dashboard');  Once I did this my routes after run would work.